# Powershell doesnt recognize script

Tags: shell, powershell, permissions

Ive created a script for users in my company to use with powershell ise and when I run it there using F5 it is working.

Ive set the executionpolicy to unrestricted as well.

Later Ive tried to open this script with powershell.exe because I need it to run straight for the users, and it gave the error:

The term "C:\users\ofir\Script\Json is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program..

What could be the problem? Thanks, Ofir.

Comment: What, exactly, did you do when `Ive tried to open this script with powershell.exe` ? Typed something (what, where, how)? Clicked something (what, where, how)?

Comment: I was right clicking the file of the Ise and changed it to be "Opened with" powershell.exe

Comment: For security reasons, Powershell scripts are not intended to be run by clicking around. Is the file name exactly `Json`? If it is, add the missing `.ps1` extension.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspect you to run the file like `powershell.exe -file C:\Users\What\Not\Json File.ps1` I could think of missing quotationmarks.

Try

```
  Powershell.exe -file "Path\To\File"
```

Comment: Without knowing the exact error, speculative answer isn't going to be helpful for others that might encounter similar problems.

Comment: Well, the error message it self gives quite some useful info, as powershell does not seem to recon the path. It even shows that the path must have whitespaces in it that were not considered. So, it is not really guessing into the blue.

Comment: Given the error message posted, I'd say this is qualified guesswork, not just speculation, +1